# How can I get the source code of the built in bullish flag chart pattern on trading view?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

How can I get the source code of the built in bullish flag chart pattern on trading view? I have tried finding it in the free indicators but could not find anything. the link for the chart pattern in trading view is as follows.
[https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE%3ANIFTY&solution=43000653209][1]

Answer (score 0):

The source code of the bullish flag chart pattern is not available. You have to implement it yourself according to the description.